# OpenCV chessboard recognition at grazing angles

Tags: opencv, camera

I need to retrieve the precise position of the intersection points of an horizontal pattern viewed from a camera at grazing angle (the angle between the camera optical axis and the horizontal is e.g. 30 degrees) with OpenCV.
My problem with this task is that, because of the grazing angle, the effective precision of the point detection is not uniform on the whole area of the target.
Right now I am using a chessboard and `findChessboardCorners` to do that, but the detection of the farthest corners is quite bad.
Is there any way to improve the results? For example, could an ArUco target give me better results?